# VirtualBox Minecraft Server

Tags: server, virtualbox, iptables, minecraft

So I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04 in VirtualBox and trying to host a server in it. I literally got everything set up, installed, and it's perfect. I forwarded my ports to 25565 TCP and UDP with this command:

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p udp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT

I read that you must not use anything below Java 6, so I'm using Java 8 now. Still didn't work. I've done everything I could find and I've spent a good day or two.

Please help, I forgot to mention. I have Bridged Connection set up too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the commands you used to forward the ports.

I'm running a Minecraft server in an Xubuntu guest OS. When I set up port forwarding I assigned my virtual machine a static IP and then made the necessary changes for port forwarding using the router's admin page (typically -- log into 192.168.1.1 but check your router user guide / manual).

You don't need Java 8. Just install the latest Java 6 or Java 7 and you'll be fine.